# WordPress in post url change in bulk

Tags: php, wordpress

I have migrated my local `WordPress` website to live server and replaced `http://localhost` url from `wp_options` table on live server sql database. Website is opening up fine on url but there are lots of broken images and links which still shows `http://localhost` link. I have around hundred of posts its much difficult for me to update each of them manually.

One way i thought off is writing a `sql query`. But i want to keep it second option is there any else way to do?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Use this [plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-migrate-db/).  Very easy to migrate your local database to live

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should learn [How to Move WordPress From Local Server to Live Site?](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-move-wordpress-from-local-server-to-live-site/) You can fix this by using this [Velvet Blues Plugin for WordPress](http://wordpress.org/plugins/velvet-blues-update-urls/) and plenty of other plugins available too for this.

Alternatively, I recommend if you are experienced enough you should use this simple sql query rather using a plugin,

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content, 'localhost/yourlocalsite/', 'www.yourlivesite.com/');
```

**Caution: Don’t forget to change the urls in query with your own local site and live site URLs.**

good luck!